# On relations between flasque , injective and fine sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

As we all know, injective sheaves are flasque. On a paracompact Hausdorff space $X$, what's the relation between flasque and fine sheaves on $X$ ? And what about fine and injective?
Recall that a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ over a topological space $X$ called flasque if for any inclusion $V \subset U$ of open sets,the restriction map from $\mathcal F(U) \to \mathcal F(V)$ is surjective.
fine sheaf over a paracompact Hausdorff space means that it is a sheaf and has a P.O.U.
Injective sheaf is a injective object in the category of abelian group sheaves.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is P.O.U.?

Comment: Partitions of unity.

Comment: "partitions of unity", more precisely, for any locally finite open cover of the space X , a partition of unity for the sheaf subordinate to the cover is a family of homomorphisms from the sheaf to itself with sum 1 such that each homomorphism is 0 outside some element of the open cover.